# How is gravitational potential energy $mgh$?

Tags: forces, energy, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy

I know the derivation that $W=Fd$, hence $F=mg$ and $d=h$ so energy gained by the body is $mgh$ considering the body on the ground to have $0$ gravitational potential energy.

But the definition of work is (as given in my book)

> Work done is the product of force and displacement caused by it in the same direction.

That means work done on a body to lift it against gravity to a certain height should be equal to the potential energy gained by it, right? My book also states that:

> $mg$ is the minimum force required to lift a body against earth's gravity(without acceleration).

But how does that make sense? Suppose a body is kept on the ground, and we apply a force $mg$ on it, won't the force of gravity and this external force cancel out and ultimately result in no movement of the body? How is the derivation of $U=mgh$ thus obtained?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of the problem is to distinguish between the *work done by a particular force* and the *net work* done by all the forces. The second is to notice  that the work done on an object depends on the process undergone.  The third is to understand that the relationship between work and potential energy is that the work done by a conservative force is proportional to the *change* in the potential energy.

Let's walk through the scenario.  A block of mass $m$ sits on the ground at position $y=0$.  There are two forces acting: the gravitational force downward and then normal force upward.  Newton's 2nd Law tells us that
$$
m\vec{a}=\vec{F}_{\textrm{net on object}} =
\vec{F}_{\textrm{G, on object by Earth}}
+\vec{N}_{\textrm{on object by ground}}\,.
$$
We'll abbreviate these as $\vec{F}_{\textrm{net}}$, $\vec{F}_{\textrm{G}}$, and $\vec{N}$.

1. In the case where the object is just sitting on the ground, the acceleration is clearly zero, and the normal and gravitational force cancel each other out.  The block doesn't move, and so the net work done by either force must be zero:
   $$
   W_{\textrm{by G}}=\int_i^f\vec{F}_{\textrm{G}}\cdot d\vec{r}=\vec{F}_{\textrm{G}}\cdot\Delta\vec{r} = 0\,
   $$
   where the second equality holds beccause the gravitational force is constant near the surface of the Earth, and the third holds because the net displacement is zero.
2. Now, someone grabs the block, accelerates it upwards, and then starts lifting the block upwards at constant speed.  Ignoring the acceleration part, as the block moves up at constant speed, the net force on it must be zero, and so the gravitational force and normal force acting must cancel, as they did above, although now $\vec{N} = \vec{N}_{\textrm{by person}}$, which we'll just call $\vec{N}$. The work done by gravity and the work done by the person lifting the block can be computed as follows:
   $$
   W_{\textrm{by G}}=-mg(y_f-y_i)\,,
   $$
   where $y_f$ and $y_i$ are the initial and final heights of the object, and
   $$
   W_{\textrm{by N}}=N_{\textrm{by hand}}(y_f-y_i)\,.
   $$
   Note that these two works are equal and opposite, and so the net work done is zero, as it must because the kinetic energy isn't changing!  However, the works done by the individual forces are non-zero.
3. Looking at the $W_{\textrm{by G}}$, we can see that we can alternatively define it as
   $$
   W_{\textrm{by G}} = -(U_f-U_i)\,,
   $$
   where we define $U = mgy$ to be the potential energy when the object is at height $i$.  Then, $U_f-U_i = mgy_f - mgy_i$ is just the change in potential energy as the object is lifted from height $y_i$ to height $y_f$.  We *could* write this as $mgy_f - mgy_i = mgh$, where $h$ is the change in height, but this isn't a great way to do things, because $h$ could be negative (if the block moves downward), and it's easy to confuse a position with a change in position is if it's not notated correctly.  I would write this as $mgy_f - mgy_i = mg\Delta y$.

---

To tie this in with the OP's specific questions, then, note that while the block is sitting on the ground, the potential energy is *constant* because its position doesn't change.  The value of the potential energy itself is a meaningless quantity; it's only *changes* in potential energy that matter, via $W = -\Delta U$.  We derive $U= mgy$ by considering the work done during a *process* in which the position of the object *changes*.

---

Last important note: the third bullet point requires a change in perspective, and without this change in perspective, things can go wrong (mixed up understandings and incorrect calculations). In our analysis above, we chose the system to be the ball, and we computed the change in kinetic energy of the ball by computing the works done by all forces acting on the ball.  If these works cancel, then the net change in kinetic energy is zero.

If instead we move to a potential energy language, we have to reconsider what we call our *system*.  Instead of thinking about the work done by the Earth via gravity on the ball, we consider a new system composed of both the Earth and the ball.  In that case, we replace the work done by the Earth on the ball by the change in potential energy of the Earth-ball system, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\Delta KE_{\textrm{ball}} &= W_{\textrm{N}}+W_{\textrm{G}} =
\Delta KE_{\textrm{ball}} = W_{\textrm{N}}-\Delta PE_{\textrm{G}}
\Longrightarrow
\\
W_{\textrm{N}} &= \Delta KE_{\textrm{ball}} + \Delta PE_{\textrm{G}}
\end{align}
Since the kinetic energy of the Earth doesn't change,
$$
\Delta KE_{\textrm{system}}  = \Delta KE_{\textrm{ball}} + \Delta KE_{\textrm{Earth}} = \Delta KE_{\textrm{ball}}\,,
$$
and so we can write
$$
W_{\textrm{ext}} = \Delta KE_{\textrm{system}} + \Delta PE_{\textrm{system}}\,,
$$
where $W_{\textrm{ext}}$ is the work done by objects *outside* the system on objects *inside* the system, or work done by *external* forces.  In this case, that is the work done by the person in lifting the ball.

Comment: Everything is cool but the problem is i haven't learnt calculus yet as it's not in 10th grade, so i just gotta take your word for it now :P Thanks though, appreciate the effort

Comment: You don't need calculus, though.  The only part where that comes in is in the *general* definition of the work done.  Since all these forces are constant, the work reduces to the product of the component of the force in the direction of the displacement times the displacement.  So you can completely ignore the integral!  Everything else is fine.

Comment: @JavaMonke Nope! The speed is in fact irrelevant, since when you compute $F_{\textrm{G},y}(y_f-y_i)$, the velocity (or even speed) doesn't even come into it!  The "ignoring" the initial acceleration part was in service of understanding how the net work might be zero while the works done by individual forces aren't.

Comment: Alright, so $W_N= \Delta PE_G$ since $\Delta KE=0$?

Comment: @JavaMonke. That *is* something that you can conclude *in this particular case*. It is decidedly *not* a general feature of these situations, and it's generally not a useful observation to make from a practical perspective.  The reason is that *there is no potential energy associated with a normal force*, and so it's best not to write things like $W_N=\Delta PE_G$ because we are liable to confuse ourselves (I have made such mistakes in the past).

Comment: Just one more question, suppose a body was accelerating for a while after being lifted from the ground, such that we apply a force $F_H>mg$ and $\Delta KE≠0$, then for $\Delta PE_G$ at a certain distance $h$ from initial point, will $W_N=mgh=\Delta PE_G$, and $\Delta KE$ at that point will be equal to $(F_H-mg)h$? So total work done by the external force $F_H$ is $mgh + F_Hh- mgh = F_Hh$? Do you think I have understood it properly?

Comment: This is exactly why I recommended not writing down $W_N=\Delta PE_G$!  That only holds for the *very specific situation* I was considering, in which the normal and gravitational forces are *equal and opposite*! What we have is that $W_G = -\Delta PE_G = -mg(y_f-y_i)$, no matter what the situation, and then $W_{F_H}=\Delta K +\Delta PE_G = \Delta K + \Delta PE_G$. In this case, you actually need to compute $W_{F_H}$, which means you need to know exactly what force $F_H$ was acting during the process.

Comment: "There is no potential energy associated with normal force" why? Isn't the work done by us when acceleration =0 (NormalForce)×(Displacement)? By normal force I mean the equal force which we are exerting on the body to produce zero acceleration

Comment: You can always calculate the work done by a force, but you *cannot* always write that work in terms of a PE.  Notice that we always write $\Delta PE = PE_f-PE_i$, so the change in potential energy (and therefore the work done by the corresponding force) only depends on the initial and final positions! But I can push (which is a normal force) a block to the right, then push it to the left back to its original position, in which case I have done a bunch of work, but since the net change in position is *zero*, there's no way to write something like $\Delta PE_f - \Delta PE_i$ that is non-zero.

Comment: I understand what you say, but considering the example you gave, I thought that if we push a box and bring it back to its original position, the net *displacement* is $0$, so work done is also $0$ so there is no gain in energy of the box anyways

Comment: That's a common misconception!  The work done is always computed by considering the component of the force *in the direction of motion*. The work is positive if the force and motion are in the same direction and negative if they are in opposite directions. When I'm pushing a box and moving it around, I'm *always* pushing in the direction motion, so in the case that I outlined, the net work done by me is definitely positive and definitely non-zero.

Comment: Oh. Never thought of it that way... I just said the way I have learnt it in school. Actually we haven't been taught components of vectors yet, so maybe I will learn it later. Thanks for the insight! You are a lifesaver!

Comment: Hey, sorry for pinging you again, I was thinking of it this way, just thought would share it here for confirmation: the net work done on a body contributes totally to $\Delta KE$ because of Work Energy Theorem, and according to definition of PE, the "minimum work" required to bring a body to some distance away from its initial position js $\Delta PE_G$, so for a  body in motion, the minimum force required is the force opposite and equal in magnitude to gravity($mg$), so the $\Delta PE_G$ is $mgh$? I actually tried to simplify your answer a bit in my mind. Am I right?

Comment: What actually irritates me to some extent is that we are ignoring the velocity of the ball while calculating the work done by $mg$ upwards; but then I thought of it this way: when the ball is accelerated, it gains some velocity. When the ball is just above the ground, *barely* touching it such that $\Delta PE_G=0$ and $\Delta KE$ slightly $>0$, that is when "minimum force required" is $mg$, and we can consider $mgh$ to be the formula for $\Delta PE_G$ according to the definition?

Comment: @march In the second equation what are $i$ and $f$ in the integral? Are they the values of $dr$ at $t_{0}$ and $t_{0}$+$dt$?

Comment: @march Also when you state that "U=mgy to be the potential energy" I would rather say it's the gravitational potential energy, since this expression only applies to work done by gravitational force.

Comment: @march also in your last example, please use $U$ instead of $P$ or the contrary to make symbols consistent cross examples.

Answer (score 4):

> Suppose a body is kept on the ground, and we apply a force  on it, won't the force of gravity and this external force cancel ...

Yes, they will cancel.  Net force = 0, acceleration = 0.

> ...our and ultimately result in no movement of the body?

acceleration = 0 does not mean velocity = 0.  If we could get the block moving  for a moment, then the $mg$ force would be sufficient to maintain that motion against gravity.  And since it is moving, there is now a non-zero displacement that can be applied.

Comment: I considered the same, but won't that minimum extra force required to give the body a certain velocity be considered too when measuring the energy gained by the ball?

Comment: You can create scenarios where it does not.  First of all there is no minimum speed, so you can make the KE arbitrarily small (much smaller than the potential energy gained).  Also, you can apply it before consideration.  Start the object moving before your reference point and only consider the work done after the reference point.

Comment: @JavaMonke Yes, and that extra force gives it kinetic energy. Then, in order for the object to stop at height $h$, you need to dampen the upward force a little, to convert that kinetic energy into potential energy. So from "unmoving at height $0$" to "unmoving at height $h$", the lifting force has gone from slightly above $mg$, to $mg$, to slightly below $mg$, averaging out to exactly $mg$.

Comment: Thanks! @Arthur

Answer (score 2):

> But the definition of work is (as given in my book)
>
> Work done is the product of force and displacement caused by it in the same direction.

That is called positive work. That's the work you do lifting the body because the force you apply is in the same direction as the displacement of the body. Positive work transfers energy to the body.

But at the same time you are doing positive work, gravity is doing negative work since its force is opposite to the direction of the displacement. Negative work takes energy away from the body. In this case, gravity takes part or all of the energy you supply the body and stores it as gravitational potential energy (GPE) of the Earth-body system.

> That means work done on a body to lift it against gravity to a certain
> height should be equal to the potential energy gained by it, right?

Yes, if the body is to have no change in kinetic energy, i.e., $\Delta KE=0$, between $0$ and the height $h$. That will be the case if the body begins and ends at rest and the net work done is $mgh-mgh=0$. The underlying principle here is the work energy theorem which states: *The net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy*at the height.

> My book also states that:
>
> $mg$ is the minimum force required to lift a body against earth's gravity(without acceleration).
>
> But how does that make sense?

Since the body starts at rest on the ground, in order to get it moving you need to apply a force $>mg$ to give it an initial acceleration. But in order for all your work to wind up as GPE, before reaching the height $h$ you need to apply a force $<mg$ to decelerate the body and bring it to rest at $h$ for a $\Delta KE$ of zero. What happens in between $0$ and $h$ does not matter, as long as the object begins and ends at rest so that $\Delta KE=0$.

Hope this helps.